# Installing metro app on own PC

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, microsoft-metro

What I mean is ... When compile app in VS Express for W8 it's being instaled in same time. Problem is that every month after first compile I get an error

> > UNABLE TO ACTIVATE WINDOWS STORE APP. THE ACTIVATION REQUEST FAILED WITH ERROR…

And thats ok since I've found out solution(delete bin and obj folders) but after next month after solving this problem I got the same error.Obviously I can manage it in same way that I did before but the problem is that if there are some data in app that data will be removed (if I remove obj and bin). 
Is there any solution for this monthly license problems with app? Can I install it for example and dont have to keep solving this issue every month also with losing some data?

Comment: Do you have an app that has been installed before and not from the current source ie Visual Studio ??????

Comment: Nope, it has been instaled only from VS

Comment: is your visual studio having a monthly license ??

Comment: Yeah! I refresh license every month.